# Regex match from start label until empty line or end label

Tags: regex

How can I match the content between a startlabel and either a empty line or an endlabel with a regex?

For example [regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/cU2tX6/1):

```
<START> some text is here. 
more text

unrelated text

<START> even more text. 
text text
<STOP>
```

It should match two matches

```
<START> some text is here. 
more text
```

and

```
<START> even more text. 
text text
<STOP>
```

The regex I came up so far is as follows (but it matches the whole text, I assume because of the (?s).* part).

```
<START>((?s).*)(\s\s|<STOP>)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use a [lazy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) for `.*` to match as few as it can. Using `.*?`:

```
(?s)(<START>.*?)(?:(?:\r*\n){2}|<STOP>)
```

Leaving out of the group what you specified as ending conditions.

1. `(?:\r*\n){2}` an empty line.
2. `<STOP>` the end label.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vI3uI9/1)

Comment: this is such a mystery to me, but thank you so much for sharing it because it just saved my bacon!

Answer (score 3):

You can design your pattern like this (with the modifier m):

```
<START>[^\n<]*(?:(?:<(?!STOP>)|\n(?!$))[^\n<]*)*(?:<STOP>|\n$|\z)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/tQ7nT3/1)

The idea is to match all that is not a `<` or a newline with `[^\n<]*`. When a `<` or a newline is reached, negative lookaheads check if they are not followed by `"STOP>"` or an end of line. If the negative lookahead succeeds then `[^\n<]*` (in the non-capturing group this time) reaches the next `<` or newline. The group is repeated until `<STOP>`, two newlines, the end of the string.

Answer (score -1):

use this pattern `(?<=<START>).+\n.+`

See demo here  https://regex101.com/r/cU2tX6/2