# Match anything under a heading until the next heading - Regex Powershell

Tags: .net, regex, powershell

I'm trying to create a regex expression which captures any content between headings for example:

```
***** Heading1 ********
content
more content
more content

***** Heading2 ********
content
more content
more content

...
```

Just to clarify, In each portion I'm trying to capture the

```
content
more content
more content
```

(There could also be more than 3 lines of content btw)

I found another post that similarly describes the issue I'm having but I wasn't able to manipulate that expression to achieve what I wanted it to do. That post can be found here: [Regex match from start label until empty line or end label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705685/regex-match-from-start-label-until-empty-line-or-end-label)

I thought about making an expression that matches everything but the headings so for example maybe something like !?(\*(.*)\*) yet that doesn't do what I want either.

Comment: Read the whole file into memory if it is notnot too large andsplit with `'(?m)^\*{3,} Heading \*{3,}'` regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expression is not the right tool to parse markdown

As you can see the spec for markdown is more complicated than just looking for asterisks http://spec.commonmark.org/0.26/#atx-headings

You can see how the parser of markdown is implemented here

https://github.com/gjtorikian/commonmarker/blob/master/ext/commonmarker/commonmarker.c

You can either pick an off-the-shelf library or if you're going to do it then might as well write a proper parser for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = @'
***** Heading1 ********
content
more content
more content

***** Heading2 ********
content
more content
more content

'@

[regex]::Matches($s, "^\*+ (?<Heading>.*?) \*+`r`n(?<Content>.*?)`r?`n\s*`r?`n", 'singleline, multiline') | 
    ForEach-Object {

        $_.Groups['Heading'].Value
        $_.Groups['Content'].Value
        "--" 

    }
```